# How to run single test class using minitest in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Gemfile looks like this:-

```
group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'capybara'#,'1.1.2'
  gem 'cucumber-rails','1.2.1'
  gem 'cucumber','1.1.4'
  gem 'rspec-rails','2.8.1'
  gem 'rspec-cells','0.1.2'
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "guard-rspec"
  gem "minitest"
  gem 'headless'
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'  
 end
```

minitest_helper.rb looks like :-

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "minitest/autorun"
require "capybara/rails"


class ControllerTest  < MiniTest::Spec
 include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
 include Capybara::DSL
 register_spec_type(/integration$/, self)
end
```

And my products_controller_test.rb looks like this:-

```
require "minitest_helper"


describe "Products Controller" do
   it "shows product's name" do  
    uname="Glasses"

    product1 = Product.create!(:name => uname, :description => uname, :no_of_items =>    3,:fee_percentage => 4)
    visit products_path
    page.text.must_include "Glasses"
  end

   end
```

BUT..after executing ruby `-Itest test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb`

I get no error,no indication to show that this test class has been loaded :-

```
ruby -Itest test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb
:public is no longer used to avoid overloading Module#public, use :public_folder instead
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/resque-1.19.0/lib/resque/server.rb:12:in `<class:Server>'
Loaded suite test/controllers/products_controller_test
Started

Finished in 0.004953 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

***its first time i am using Minitest...***

Comment: I got the same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Gemfile is a little heavy... If you remove all the RSpec references, you'll run just fine.

(The "describe" and "it" methods are being usurped by rspec)

Remove:

```
 gem 'rspec-rails','2.8.1'
 gem 'rspec-cells','0.1.2'
```

Comment: Thanks.....after making few changes in Gemfile..it worked using ruby -Itest test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb